# Jetpack Compose - TextField text alignment issue + cutoff

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a TextField "square" input field in which I want a single character to display at 24.dp.

The containing Box I have set to 52.dp, so there is plenty of room to have this character display.  However, for some reason, it's bumping down the character and cutting it off.  I imagine I'm missing something simple here.

Code below, and the result of what it currently looks like:

```
var inputChar by remember {
    mutableStateOf("2")
}

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(52.dp)
        .border(
            width = 1.dp,
            color = Color.Black,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp)
        )
        .aspectRatio(1f)
) {
    TextField(
        value = inputChar,
        onValueChange = { newText ->
            inputChar = newText
        },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
            .merge(TextStyle(fontSize = 24.sp)),
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
            backgroundColor = Color.LightGray,
            cursorColor = Color.Black,
            focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
        ),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp),
        singleLine = true,
    )
}
```

[image: cutoff text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `layout inspector` is very helpful in these situations :) It showed that there is by default an inner padding between the actual text and the edges of the textfield. To remove it, you will probably have to make a custom composable using `BasicTextField` - in the proposed solution below it is named as `SquareTextField`.

I also moved the border inside the texfield rather than have it as an outer parent. Hope this helps! :)

```
@Composable
private fun ExampleContent() {
    var inputChar by remember {
        mutableStateOf("2")
    }

    SquareTextField(
        modifier = Modifier.size(52.dp),
        value = inputChar,
        onValueChange = { newText ->
            inputChar = newText
        },
        textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current
            .copy(textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
            .merge(TextStyle(fontSize = 24.sp)),
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
            backgroundColor = Color.LightGray,
            cursorColor = Color.Black,
            focusedBorderColor = Color.Black,
            unfocusedBorderColor = Color.Black,
        ),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
    )
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
private fun SquareTextField(
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    isError: Boolean = false,
    textStyle: TextStyle = TextStyle.Default,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default,
    singleLine: Boolean = true,
    colors: TextFieldColors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(),
    visualTransformation: VisualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
) {
    BasicTextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        modifier = modifier,
        textStyle = textStyle,
        keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
        visualTransformation = visualTransformation,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        enabled = enabled,
        singleLine = singleLine,
    ) { innerTextField ->
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .border(
                    width = 1.dp,
                    color = Color.Black,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp)
                )
        ) {
            TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox(
                value = value,
                visualTransformation = visualTransformation,
                innerTextField = innerTextField,
                singleLine = singleLine,
                enabled = enabled,
                isError = isError,
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                colors = colors,
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp), // Remove the padding
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer on this, and I'm sure it may work, but why does this solution require hundreds of lines of code just to get a square TextField working?!  Is there something easier from Compose?  I literally need a box that allows an input character, lol. that's it!

Comment: It may seem like a lot of lines, but that is probably just because I extracted the code to make a separate and thus **reusable** component that will save you a lot of lines of code along the way. You could definitely rewrite this to a half, depends on what your approach is. You may also refer to this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/189971673) regarding this topic. However, I agree, that it would be nicer to just remove the padding with a single line.

Comment: Yep reusable components are always a good thing. Sorry I was a bit taken aback with the number of lines of code, but I think I have a better understanding now.  This is working great, and thank you so much for your answer!  Accepted